# state with is array is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    
    function App() {
      
        const [thingsArray, setThingsArray] = React.useState(["Thing 1", "Thing 2"])
        
        function addItem() {
          
            setThingsArray(prevThingsArray => prevThingsArray.push("Thing 3"))
        }
        
        const thingsElements = thingsArray.map(thing => <p key={thing}>{thing}</p>)
        
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
                {thingsElements}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

According to my understanding when we want to change state we should use a call back function inside the function which we use to update state . And in that callback function we use a parameter to reference to current value of state as we should not directly change state .
In below example i am using the same idea but it is not working , can anyone explain me the reason and logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

You should push the following item like so:

`setThingsArray(prevThingsArray => [...prevThingsArray,"Thing 3"])`

Basically, you are getting the old array values and adding "Thing 3".

Comment: Why? What's different from push?

Comment: @v.k. I believe the reason was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437006/19981230